# render reactjs content in app

Tags: reactjs, render

When I see the source code of my web page, made in reactjs the content in #app I can not see it, how can I make it to see the content

Comment: but the questions is How can I program for that code to be generated when I see the source code, why do I think that for seo it is wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to make use of server-side rendering. What you see in the source code is what is being sent to the browser from the server. In typical React applications, the content is only created via JavaScript after the page loads. Only a bare `<body>` with some `<div>` is being sent to the browser.

This repository should show you how it can be achieved: https://github.com/mhart/react-server-example